# Add prompt after user selects file

Tags: c#, web-services, openfiledialog

I have added an open file dialog box to my client application so that the used can select a specific file they want to send to the web service.

However the file gets sent the moment the file has been selected, whereas I would like to have a secondary prompt e.g. "Send - 'file name' Button Yes. Button No." to pop up after they have selected the file.

This would be incase the user selected the wrong file they would have a chance to see which one they selected.

So far I have the following code -

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Read txt File
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);

            myReader.Close();

            string csv = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

I need the prompt to come up after they have selected the file but not sure how to do this so any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the second check manually after the first dialog:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //Read txt File
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Message", "Title",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)==DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            myReader.Close();
            string csv = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
```

etc etc

Information on [MessageBox.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show.aspx).  You can get information on the possible results/options from here.

You could ensure that the user sees the file to be uploaded by making the message something like:

```
"Are you sure you want to upload " + openFileDialog1.FileName;
```

Comment: It should be Message first before Title in Show() method.

Comment: Brilliant stuff @Sam Holder, just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

MessageBox.Show(...) is the method you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a message box:

```
 if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Upload {0}, are you sure?", openFileDialog1.FileName), "Please Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
 {
     // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

A sample of the code modified.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

     if(dr == DialogResult.Yes )
        StreamReader myReader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        // more code
     else
        // do something else
```